# Apache not responding due to port mapping

Tags: apache-2.2, centos

```
[centos@staging03 ~]$ sudo netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.2:80                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      18336/varnishd      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:80                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      15636/fcgi-         
tcp        0      0 172.31.22.60:80             0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1557/nginx          
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1274/sshd           
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1524/master         
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:443               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      15636/fcgi-         
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6082              0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      18335/varnishd      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:11211             0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1252/memcached      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6379              0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1063/redis-server 1 
tcp        0      0 :::22                       :::*                        LISTEN      1274/sshd           
tcp        0      0 :::3306                     :::*                        LISTEN      1406/mysqld
```

So in the above, it's the mapping of the faulty server.

```
[root@webdev01 ~]# sudo netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.2:80                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1679/varnishd       
tcp        0      0 172.31.23.5:80              0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1644/nginx          
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:80                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1620/httpd          
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1177/sshd           
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1439/master         
tcp        0      0 172.31.23.5:443             0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1644/nginx          
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:443               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1620/httpd          
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6082              0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1678/varnishd       
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:11211             0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1155/memcached      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6379              0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1072/redis-server 1 
tcp        0      0 :::22                       :::*                        LISTEN      1177/sshd           
tcp        0      0 :::3306                     :::*                        LISTEN      1315/mysqld         
[root@webdev01 ~]#
```

And here's the mapping in the server it works.

```
# FILE: /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
User apache Group apache

ServerAdmin root@localhost

UseCanonicalName Off

DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

<Directory /> Options FollowSymLinks AllowOverride None </Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/html">

Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

AllowOverride None

Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

This is my apache configs

The content of my http file:

```
<?php print_r('hello'); ?>
```

File permission is:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root apache 19 Nov  4 17:02 test.php
```

For some reason, the port 80 is mapped to fcgi instead of httpd, but looking at the configs of both server, I didn't find any difference, so I am wondering what's causing httpd to not be mapped correctly. Is there any config file I am missing somehow?

Comment: You are not looking at the complete Apache configuration. Look for the `Listen` directive.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is fcgi is running on server 1 and not server 2.

Check your service manager.